# How to send/get data using POST/GET http method in Java - REST API

Tags: java, rest, http

I am trying to send data (Add a new Book) with the help of http method POST/PUT method but I tried and couldn't figure out.

This is my `Book.java` class which stores Book values

```
package bookservice;

public class Book {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private double price;

    public Book() {
    }

    public Book(int id, String title, double price) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

And this is my `Books.java` with `addBook()` and `removeBook()` methods:

```
package bookservice;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Books {
    private static ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
    static {
        books.add(new Book(1, "The Outliers", 500));
        books.add(new Book(2, "World Is Flat", 550));
    }

    public static List<Book> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }

    // method to add books
    public void addBook(int id, String name, double price) {
        books.add(new Book(id, name, price));
    }

    // method to remove a book with a given book ID
    public Book removeBook(int bookID) {

        // search the book in entire ArrayList for the given book ID
        for (Book bookToRemove : books) {
            if (bookToRemove.getId() == bookID) {
                //remove the book
                books.remove(bookToRemove);
                // if found
                return bookToRemove;
            }
        }
        // if not found
        return null;
    }

}
```

And this is my `BookService.java` which handles RestApi

```
package bookservice;

import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/books")
public class BookService {
    List<Book> books;
    public BookService() {
        books = Books.getBooks();
    }
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Book> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }
    @Path("{id}")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Book getBook(@PathParam("id") int id) {
          for(Book b : books) {
              if ( b.getId() == id)
                   return b;
          }
          // book with the given id is not found, so throw 404 error
          throw new NotFoundException(); 
    }


}
```

And this is the `index.html`, (here I haven't add fields to type `bookID` and a `button` to save data, because I can do that later when the implementation is done)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Book client</title>
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="book.js"></script>
</head>

<h2>Books Client</h2>
Book Id :
<br />
<input type="text" id="id" />
<button onclick="getDetails()">Details</button>
<p />
<div id="title"></div>
<p />
<div id="price"></div>
</html>
```

And this is `books.js` with `ajax` call

```
/**
 * 
 */

function getDetails() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url : "http://localhost:8080/BookService/rest/books/" + $("#id").val(),
        type : "GET",
        contentType : "application/json",
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // here is your json.
            // process it
            $("#title").text(data.title);
            $("#price").text(data.price);

        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $("#title").text("Sorry! Book not found!");
            $("#price").text("");
        },
        timeout : 120000,
    });
};
```

**My Problem is:**

**1.) How to Update the `BookService.java` to add a book (using the POST http method) and to remove a book (using DELETE http method).**

**2. How to test the updated Service with a browser or `Soap ui` before proceeding to update the client?**

I have implemented the functions but I am stuck with these two questions...

Comment: What did you try for question 1? For question 2, you can use postamn https://www.getpostman.com/ or curl https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL. Those are much easier than SOAP ui.

Comment: Can you give me a link for any examples on question 1? How to send `post` data using java `http` methods in `jersey` ?